# Use StackBlur as background Image for a div

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, blur

I would like, if possible, to use the [StackBlur.js](http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) to set the background of a DIV to a specified image, let's say this one: 
http://img.youtube.com/vi/2UphAzryVpY/mqdefault.jpg, but I really don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: please share that code that you've written to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code required is only about 7 lines long...here it is! **:-)**

Here's an example of how to use Quasimondo's StackBlur.js to blur an image and set it as the background of a div:

[image]

```js
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/idcard1.png";
function start(){
    blurImageToBackground(img,document.getElementById('myDiv'));
}

function blurImageToBackground(img,element){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=img.width;
    c.height=img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    stackBlurCanvasRGBA(c,0,0,c.width,c.height,8)
    element.style.background='url('+c.toDataURL()+')';
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#myDiv{width:472px; height:286px; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flozz/StackBlur/master/StackBlur.js"></script>
<h4>Please be patient while the image blurs and loads :-)</h4>
<div id=myDiv width=472 height=286></div>
```

**Note:** StackBlurJS requires the use of `context.getImageData` so be sure that any image you want to blur is served in the same domain as you webpage. (This is a cross-origin security requirement).

Comment: oh, your last "Note" is very bad for me. I want to use it for http://www.ihavenotv.com/ and all the images are from 3rd party servers :)

Comment: Cross-origin restriction exists for very good security reasons and cannot be violated or worked around. You must get those 3rd party servers to agree to serve their images with the appropriate headers that satisfy cross-origin security restrictions.  Otherwise you can't blur the images from 3rd party servers and you will have to redesign your app. Stackoverflow's @KenFyrstenberg includes coded a pseudo-blur that meets cross-origin restrictions. It's not a true-blur, but it still looks nice: https://github.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js (He coded several versions--you need the pseudo-blur).

Comment: thanks markE for the explanations. Can you build a jsfiddle for this realtime blur, for the background of  a div (by using canvas)? I'll give you a large beer, through paypal :P